# RTE in safecracker submits form when clicking 'link' or 'quotes'

Tags: safecracker, richtext

very strange behaviour when using the rich text editor in a safecracker form on the frontsite.  Every works as expected except 2 buttons from the toolset: 'link' and 'quote'. When clicking these button, the safecracker form itself gets submitted.

Anyone?
rg,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found what was causing this.  3 things that needed to be changed

1. 2 conflicting jQuery libraries were loaded on the same page.  For the form to behave normal I needed to keep the one included in safecracker using the include_jquery="yes" parameter and the other one was removed from the page
2. For some other functionalities on the site we load foundation.min.js - I needed to leave this out the form pages
3. And for cosmetic faults I needed to load  at the top of the page

Hope that might help someone someday!
T.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I was encountering this same issue. More specifically, I think the solution is using jQuery 1.7.2; when SafeCracker injects its own jQuery library, that's the version it uses. I was calling 1.10.2 in my <head>, but changing that to 1.7.2 (without changing anything else) solved this for me.